# How to make a 'blueprint' of all possible relationships and nodes in Neo4J with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What I want to create is a blueprint of my datamodel.
What I mean with blueprint is a newly created datamodel, where every node is created only once; every node with a unique label (with eiter none, one or multiple labels) from my real database must be copied and shown once.

For every unique node in this blueprint, I also need a relationship blueprint. So for every *different* relationship (either by name, direction or connected nodes) I also need only one representation.

Example: Say i have have 4 nodes, of which 2 are Persons and 2 are Companies; then in the blueprint only 2 nodes are shown. These are the relationships:

```
(c)-[:LIKES]->(p)
(c)-[:LIKES]->(p)
(c)-[:LIKES]->(c)
(c)-[:LIKES]->(c)
(p)<-[DISLIKS]-(c)
```

These relationships show 3 unique relationships, based on name, direction and nodes connected.
So for this blueprint, the outcome must be 2 unique nodes with 3 unique relationships.

I've been struggling with the code to realize this for a while.
Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Neo4j built-in procedure `db.schema.visualization()` is what you're looking for : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/procedures/#procedure_db_schema_visualization

Example :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a blueprint of your datamodel in Neo4j, you can use the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH DISTINCT labels(n) AS labelList, properties(n) AS propertyMap
MERGE (b:Blueprint)-[:HAS_LABEL]->(l:Label{name:labelList})
MERGE (b)-[:HAS_NODE]->(n:Node{properties:propertyMap})
WITH b, id(n) AS nodeId, [(n)-[r]->(m) | type(r)] AS relTypes
UNWIND relTypes AS relType
MERGE (b)-[:HAS_REL_TYPE]->(rt:RelType{name:relType})
WITH b, nodeId, [(n)-[r]->(m) | [type(r), startNode(r).id, endNode(r).id]] AS relList
UNWIND relList AS rel
MERGE (b)-[:HAS_REL]->(r:Rel{type:rel[0], startNodeId:rel[1], endNodeId:rel[2]})
```

Note that the query stores the properties of each node as a map, and the start and end node IDs of each relationship. This allows you to reconstruct the original data model if necessary.